# How to design a middleware between two existing systems

Tags: java, spring, jira, middleware, distributed-system

I have to analyse two systems : one is JIRA (ticketing system) and the other is a planning tool system. Then i have to make a middelware between them. I dont know how and where to start fom. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: ActiveMQ, Kafka, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the api endpoints the two systems expose and know what data can be made available by two systems.  Then based on the information the middleware application can then collect the data from both systems and make decisions from there.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you like add a few more technical details that I could work with? Like how do I find the api endpoints of a system. and how to know which middleware to use and how to implement a middleware? Like which programming language etc?

Comment: For jira you can have a look at https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/   and I am not sure what planning tool you are using but check from the vendor website if they are exposing any endpoints for programmatic  access to resources .  And any language that you are comfortable with it should be ok

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out today. The planning tool I want to work upon is Cplace